# Pass database data from express.js server to react.js component

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

This is a react app with an express.js backend.  I have a mysql database connected to my server.js file and it seems to be connected fine. My issue is I want to pass that data to my react app and display it there.

My server.js database connection

```
app.get('api/listitems', (req, res) => {     

connection.connect();    
connection.query('SELECT * from list_items', (error, results, fields) => {    
    if (error) throw error;    
    res.send(results)    
});  
connection.end(); 

});
```

So this should grab the 'list_items' records from the database

Below is my react.js code. I would like to display the records under the grocery list h3.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ['first item']
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Grocery List</h3>
        {this.state.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I know this is a simple concept but I am new to backend development. The tutorials I have found have gotten me to this point, but I have had an issue finding one that simply explains how to pass and display data from the backend to frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a GET request to your backend to asynchronously fetch the data. If you want the data when your `App` component first mounts, you can use `fetch` in `componentDidMount` to call to your backend endpoint. Here's an example, with a `loading` fallback and basic error handling:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false
  }
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    // Pick whatever host/port your server is listening on
    fetch('localhost:PORT/api/listitems')
      .then(res => { // <-- The `results` response object from your backend
        // fetch handles errors a little unusually
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        // Convert serialized response into json
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        // setState triggers re-render
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Grocery List</h3>
        // The app will render once before it has data from the
        // backend so you should display a fallback until
        // you have data in state, and handle any errors from fetch
        {this.state.loading ? <p>Loading...</p>
          : this.state.error ? <p>Error during fetch!</p>
          : (
              <ul>
                this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
              </ul>
            )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`fetch` won't reject on HTTP error status (404, 500), which is why the first `.then` is a little odd. The `.catch` will log the response here with the status, but if you want to see the error message from the server, you'll need to do something like this:

```
if (!res.ok) {
  return res.text().then(errText => { throw errText });
}
```

See See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for more information, or explore other data fetching libraries like `axios`.

Comment: It keeps throwing me this error for some reason. "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): err.text is not a function" and when I comment that line out it only returns the "Error during fetch!" string under the grocery list... There is something else that must be missing.  I checked all of the database connections to make sure they are find and everything else checks out.

Comment: Could it be a port issue? The express.js server runs on port 5000 and the react-app runs on 3000.  I am using a mysql database from mamp.  Mamp says mysql is running on port 3306.  Not sure if that matters.  Express does print out the records I want on the terminal when I first launch it. So I know express is pulling the appropriate data.

Comment: I've updated my example, that `.catch` was expecting an error in the response, but it wasn't handling connection errors, which it sounds like you might have. This way should be a little more robust.

Comment: Re: ports, it sounds like 5000 is right, it'll be the port where your express server is listening for requests to `api/listitems` (not the DB port). You probably have `app.listen(SOME_PORT, callback)` somewhere in your express code, it should be that one.

Also endpoints usually begin with a slash: `/api/listitems` - that could be part of the problem. The edited code above should give you better error logging to debug it.

Comment: So I have played with this more and am still having issues.  I used third party dbs and those actually display with axios and the fetch api, but my localhost api still will not work. I keep getting these errors in the console. net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch. There has to be an issue with this localhost api. Something simple I am missing.

Comment: It's hard to know what could be wrong without seeing the rest of your code, but I would say:

Comment: 1. Make sure your express app is listening (do you have an `app.listen` somewhere in your express code?)
2. Your database methods are asynchronous, but you're calling them as if they were synchronous. Should be more like this example: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp
3. Instead of throwing an error from your query, you should probably return a 500 response with the error
4. Add console logs/debuggers until you narrow down where the problem is originating

Comment: I figured the problem out.  It ended up being a CORS issued. I needed to put the bottom code in my server.js.  `app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");      
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
     Content-Type, Accept");      
     next();      
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
**index.js**

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store, { history } from './store';

const route = (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
render(route,document.getElementById('app'))

**action/listItemAction.js**

export const ListItemSuccess = (data) => {
    return {type: 'GET_LIST_ITEMS'};
}

export const getListItems = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems')
        .then(res => {
           dispatch(ListItemSuccess(res));
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            throw(error);
        })      
    };
}

**reducers/listItems.js**

const listItems = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_LIST_ITEMS':
      return action.res.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default listItems;

**store.js**

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import listItems from './reducers/listItems.js';

const store = createStore(listItems,  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  ));

export default store;

**App.js**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.scss';
import getListItems from './action/listItemAction.js

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };

  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getListItems().then(() => {
      this.setState({data: this.props.listItems, isLoading:false});
    }).catch(error => {
        throw(error);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Grocery List</h3>
        {this.state.isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p>
          : this.state.error ? <p>Error during fetch!</p>
          : (
              <ul>
                this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
              </ul>
            )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      listItems: state.listItems
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getListItems: bindActionCreators(getListItems, dispatch),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am looking for something more vanilla.  I am new to this stuff and working myself up.  I do not know much about redux or axios yet.  I am sure those make it easier but for sake of time I just want a basic javascript, react solution. Thanks!